# Akka-stream implicitly change execution thread

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, akka-stream

During development of app with java+akka-stream I faced one strange behaviour.
According my understanding of akka-stream's documentation processing thread should not change without explicit declaration of async() operator, but looks like it changes

Below is the part of code which I run:

```
 private CompletableFuture<Done> getStreamCf() {
     return CompletionStage<Done> completionStage = createSource() //rest requests, .async() inside
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("main start. {}", param);
          return param;
        })
        .via(transformingFlow())
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("main end. {}", param);
          return param;
        })
        .via(saveFlow())
        .toMat(Sink.ignore(), Keep.right())
        .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(t -> {
          log.error("Error in stream. Stopping", t);
          return (Supervision.Directive) Supervision.stop();
        }))
        .run(actorSystem);
  }
        
        
  private Flow<FooEntity, FooEntity, NotUsed> transformingFlow() {
    Flow<FooEntity, FooEntity, NotUsed> transformingFlow = Flow
        .<FooEntity>create()
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("async start. {}", param);
          return param;
        })
        .grouped(batchSize)
        .via(batchFlow())
        .mapConcat(param -> param)
        .via(chainFlow())
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("async end. {}", param);
          return param;
        })
        .map(shallowCopy()).async();

    return transformingFlow;
  }
  
  
  
  private Flow<FooEntity, FooEntity, NotUsed> chainFlow() {
    Flow<FooEntity, FooEntity, NotUsed> transformChainFlow = Flow.create();

    for (Transformer transformer : transformerList) {
      transformChainFlow = transformChainFlow.filter((Predicate<FooEntity>) fooEntity -> {       
        log.info("Transformer: {}, entity: {}", transformer.getClass().getName(), fooEntity);
        return transformer.apply(fooEntity);
      });
    }

    return Flow
        .<FooEntity>create()
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("chain start. {}", param);
          return param;
        })
        .via(metricStart("metricName"))
        .via(transformChainFlow)
        .via(metricEnd("metricName"))
        .map(param -> {
          log.info("chain end. {}", param);
          return param;
        });
  }
```

Log output for one of elements in stream:

```
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-12] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : main start. flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [lt-dispatcher-9] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : async start. flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : chain start. flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Start metric: metricName
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer1, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer2, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer3, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer4, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer5, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer6, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer7, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer8, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer9, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer10, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer11, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer12, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : Transformer: foo.bar.Transformer13, entity: flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-11] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : End metric: Name: metricName
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-11] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : chain end. flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-11] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : async end. flowEntityValue
INFO 23 --- [t-dispatcher-10] foo.bar.ProcessingClass   : main end. flowEntityValue
```

The problem is that operators within transformingFlow() (between "async start." and "async end.") executed in different threads. But from my point of view they should be executed in the same thread/actor

Also during experiments I have found few details:

1. if I replace ".filter()" in code below by ".via(Flow.create().filter(...)) then akka can change thread between any of "Transformers"

```
 transformChainFlow = transformChainFlow.filter((Predicate<FooEntity>) fooEntity -> {       
        log.info("Transformer: {}, entity: {}", transformer.getClass().getName(), fooEntity);
        return transformer.apply(fooEntity);
      });
```

2. Absence of .async() in transformingFlow() fixes the issue (But this is not a solution in my case, really transformingFlow should be wrapped by partitioning-async-merge, in this case issue is also reproducible)
3. This issue is not permanent, not all elements affected, number of affected items different from run to run.
4. Explicit .async() works as expected (thread change between "async end" and "main end")

Details:

1. Akka stream version: com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.13:2.6.16
2. There are no more .async() except mentioned
3. Not able to reproduce apart of current app and and as a result not able to provide runnable example

The questions:

1. Is there any reason for akka streams to not execute transformingFlow() operations in single thread?
2. Is there dependencies between .via() and .async()? Can akka-stream change thread in case of .via() operator? Is there any documentation regarding this?
3. How to force execution of flow creted in transformingFlow() within one thread and basically prevent such behaviour for other similar cases?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens when you run with a `batchSize` of 1?

Comment: Hi. Looks like it doesn't work. With batchSize = 1 I don't see thread NAME change, But after additional investigation of logs I have found often overlaps of chainFlow() executions(logs are syncronious). So looks like akka stops processing of element, takes other element and later returns to the first one. 
I'm don't see original issue with batchSize=1, but issue is very context dependent and looks like root cause is still present (looks like thread change still present,  but fortunately sometimes it is the same thread as was)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to reproduce this issue on sample code. <strike>https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/31443 Issue reported</strike>

UPD: According to developer's comment on git this is expected behaviour. Akka stream may change processing threads and care about synchronization in case of thread change